# How to add Stop function to my audio player on android?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playback

I have multiple audio file on **res/raw** folder, and the audio name is save on a database. So when the program wants to play audio, audio named will called from database with a function.
FYI, I build an app for ITP TOEFL test. And I made this part for listening section.
And the problem is when I want to go to the next question, the audio will still playing, I wish to add stop function to same button that I use to start play the audio.

Here's the part of my codes that play the audio

variable declare:

```
private static MediaPlayer mp;
```

component initialitations:

```
mainkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            mainkan.setEnabled(false);
                go(audioSoal);
            }
    });
```

**mainkan* means "play"

and this is the main funciton to play audio, which is "string audio" comes from database and pointing to audio files on **res/raw** folder

```
public void go(String audio){
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+audio, null, this.getPackageName());
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(section3db.this, resId);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e){
            // TODO auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            // TODO auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0){
            mainkan.setEnabled(true);
        }
});
}
```

can someone help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your problem? Clear the question.

Comment: the problem is i want to add stop function to stop playing the audio when i go to the next question

Answer (score 0):

call this method on any button click event:

```
mp.stop();
```

this will stop the player.

if you want to pause, then do this :

```
mp.pause();
```

Comment: it works, but on the next question, the audio is not loaded.
is this the problem with: `onCompletion` function?

Comment: on completion, check if it is playing by this :

mp.isPlaying();

if it returns true then call mp.stop() and then mp.reset() else just mp.reset()

check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Welcome bro... just hit the up button... and mark it as useful.. :)